# When to use Sequelize with MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I am trying to learn SQL database with Nodejs as I have worked only with NoSQL(Mongodb) with Nodejs. I have installed mysql database and gotten to a point where I can retrieve data from mysql database using Nodejs.

I was trying to setup a user auth using Nodejs, MySQL and possibly JWT. Most of the auth tutorials that I found online for this uses Sequelize. I have never used sequelize before.

Is it a good idea to use sequelize just for user authentication or is sequelize something that is going to be useful/recommended for other parts of my application where I have to pull data from my database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Object-Relational Mapping is a method that uses an object-oriented paradigm to query and access data from a database. ORM is as fond of objects as developers are, and it is available for any programming language of your choice.

- They write correct and optimized SQL queries, thereby eliminating the hassle for developers
- They make the code easier to update, maintain, and reuse as the developer can think of, and manipulate data as objects
- ORMs will shield your application from SQL injection attacks since the framework will filter the data for you!
- It also provided added features like connection pool management.
- ORMs provide the concept of Database Abstraction which makes switching databases (Switch from maria db to MySQL or vice versa without changing any of business logic) easier and creates a consistent code base for your application.

Reference:
ORM: Rethinking Data as Objects
ORM: Rethinking Data as Objects (2018). Available at: https://blog.yellowant.com/orm-rethinking-data-as-objects-8ddaa43b1410 (Accessed: 24 April 2021).

Answer (score 2):

First of all, Sequelize is a promise-based ORM for Node.js.

ORM or Object Relation Mapping is a process of mapping between objects and relation database systems. An ORM acts like an interface between two system. ORM provide advantages for developers from basic ones like saving time and effort and rather focusing on business logic. The code is robust instead of redundant. ORM helps in managing queries for multiple tables in an effective manner. Lastly, an ORM (like sequelize) is capable to connect with different databases (which comes in handy when switching from one database to another).

**Finally, Sequelize has nothing specific to do user authentication. You can use other ORM for that as well.**